# How do I use Base64 and exclude special characters +/= from string?

Tags: ruby, base64

I am currently using Ruby's 'base64'  but the strings that are created have special characters like /+= .

How do I remove these and still make sure that my decode works in the future?

Essentially I want alphanumeric to be used.

Comment: `+/=` are all part of what the base64 standard is... Otherwise, how'd you make it "64" (26 lowercase letters + 26 uppercase letters + 10 decimal digits = 62... Missing two to reach 64, and one to tell what length the last group was). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than invent something new, I'd use `Base64.urlsafe_encode64` (and its counterpart `Base64.urlsafe_decode64`) which is basically base64 with + and / replaced with - and _. This conforms to rfc 4648 so should be widely understandable

Answer (score 2):

If you want alphanumeric, I think it is better and is practical to use base 36. Ruby has built-in encoding/decoding up to base 36 (26 letters and 10 numbers).

```
123456.to_s(36)
# => "qglj"

"qglj".to_i(36)
# => 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Integer
  Base62_digits = [*("0".."9"), *("a".."z"), *("A".."Z")]

  def base_62
    return "0" if zero?
    sign = self < 0 ? "-" : ""
    n, res = self.abs, ""
    while n > 0
      n, units = n.divmod(62)
      res = Base62_digits[units] + res
    end
    sign + res
  end

end

p 124.base_62 # => "20"
```

This could be adapted to handle lower bases, but it may be sufficient as is.